# ICS 4.0.3 AVD not showing online

Tags: android, adb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-virtual-device

Here I have an application, which is supposed to be run on 4.0.3 AVD (as selected in properties).
[image: Properties]

But as soon as I run the app, it automatically starts in 2.2 AVD.

So, I've change the run option from "Run configurations", and set it to `Always prompt to pick up device`.

[image]

Now I have both 2.2 and 4.0.3 AVD running:

[image]

But as soon as I run the app, eclipse gives the list of online devices I have, and there is only 1 device (2.2) online:
[image]

How can I make my app run on 4.0.3 AVD?

Comment: Is this scenario always reproducible? I suggest you to simply restart your eclipse or machine and try to reproduce.

Comment: No, it's always the same. When I run the app, it opens new 4.0.3 AVD every time. I mean, the system doesn't see, that there is already one AVD running, it starts another.

Comment: oh k. Can you simply run these commands from your DOS prompt. adb kill-server  and adb start-server. Try again to start your app.

Comment: Just an FYI, Android 2.2 (API 8) isn't Gingerbread, it's *Froyo*.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I have seen it happening few times but not always.

Comment: @VendettaDroid, adb kill-server and adb start-server solved the question. Thank you. Post it as an answer, just for the other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this problem is solved by two simple commands, I recommend you to run these two commands from your DOS prompt(In windows) or shell (in case of Linux)

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Comment: In Eclipse, you can also open the DDMS perspective, in the devices window click on the dropdown and select Reset adb.